# Set the limit of a specific query set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have an api view which returns some dropdown options. I am trying to set the queryset limit in order to avoid the pagination. I tried the follow but i get error: `Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.` . If i remove the [:100000] it is ok

```
class TestViewSet(
    GenericViewSet,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
):

queryset = models.Test.objects.select_related('user').all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        base_qs = super(TestViewSet, self).get_queryset()
        if self.action == 'get_dropdown_options':
            base_qs = base_qs.filter(
                user_id=self.request.get_session()['user_id']
            )[:100000]
        return base_qs
```

Comment: Why are you unable to use pagination here?  That's what its for.

Comment: Django Rest Framework [Pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) is the real answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occured because once you slice your queryset than you can not perform queryset operations on it because after slicing it will become a list.
And now answer to your question(if you dont want to user pagination) you can do something like:

```
q_ids = base_qs.filter(
            user_id=self.request.get_session()['user_id']
        ).values_list('id', flat=True)[:100000]
```

and than

```
base_qs.filter(
            user_id=self.request.get_session()['user_id'], id__in=q_ids
        )
```